# What web server (IIS 7.5) did a user last connect or sent a request to?

Tags: iis-7.5

This seems like simple question but I have yet to find a clear and recent answer.  Here's why I'm looking for this information:

PROBLEM:  We load balance 8 web servers and every server hosts the same sites.  We sometimes run into situations where a specific user receives errors while doing something and in order to diagnose and correct the problem we need to determine what server the user last connected to.  In some cases the issue is reproducible on all servers but in other cases it can only be reproduced on a specific server, which is why we need to find it.  Currently, we do the following to find the bad server:

1) Remove all servers from the balancer except one 
2) Have the user attempt to reproduce the problem 
3) If the problem can't be reproduced, repeat the same process with the next server.

This is time consuming and frustrating to our customers and I'm trying to find a better/faster way of finding the affected server.  I've done a lot of reading but so far I've only found one article from back in 2005 (IIS 6) that answers my question:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/10/08/howto-see-who-is-logged-into-iis.aspx

Is what's described in this article still true today, 10 years later?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can't the error reporting mechanism include the machine name/address/etc.?

Comment: Hi David.  What reporting mechanism are you referring to? Are you talking about modifying the site itself and make it report the machine name along with the error?  I know that's an option and we might need to move on that direction but it would take our developers a while to get to it.  I was hoping to find something that could be done other than making changes to the site.